# Compare rows in one table with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7

I tried to compare rows in one table that I have. The table is like this:

`table`

```
id - fid - tp - ct

11 - 222 - 1 - 1
12 - 222 - 2 - 0
13 - 222 - 3 - 0

14 - 333 - 1 - 3
15 - 333 - 2 - 2
16 - 333 - 3 - 0

17 - 555 - 1 - 2
18 - 444 - 1 - 0
19 - 555 - 2 - 0
20 - 444 - 2 - 0
21 - 444 - 3 - 0
22 - 555 - 3 - 0
```

I have 3 rows for comparing, and they had tp 1,2,3 for each one with the same fid and different id. The question is, how can I compare three of them to return?

For example,

```
if (t1 == 0){ // check t1
   return t1;
}else if (t1 > 0 AND t2 == 0){ // check t2
   return t2;
}else if (t1 > 0 AND t2 > 0 AND t3 == 0){ // check t3
   return t3;
}
```

**more explanation**

For example, if `ct` of the `tp 1` is equal to `0` so we return it, and `tp 2` should compare with `tp 1` if `ct` of the `tp 1` is larger than `0` so we can return `tp 2`. if `ct` of the `tp 2` and `tp 1` is larger than `0` return `tp 3`. (all of them have the same `fid`)

the result should be like this:

```
===================
id | fid | tp | ct
-------------------
12 | 222 | 2  | 0
-------------------
16 | 333 | 3  | 0
-------------------
18 | 444 | 1  | 0
-------------------
19 | 555 | 2  | 0
===================
```

I can handle this part without SQL. I can return all rows and compare them and return the result that I want, but It's not a good solution, Because I want to handle all this part just with MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want the first time that `ct = 0` for each `fid` based on the id.  That suggests:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by fid order by id) as seqnum
      from t
      where ct = 0
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

EDIT:

In older versions of MySQL, you can use:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (select min(t2.id)
              from t t2
              where t2.ct = 0 and t2.fid = t.fid
             ) as min_id
      from t
      where ct = 0
     ) t
where id = min_id
```

Comment: thank you, @Gordon, I updated the question to explain a little better than what I want to do, I never used `partition by` before. Could you explain a little about this? I got a syntax error while trying to use it.

Comment: @Milad . . . This requires MySQL version 8.0 which was released several years ago.

Comment: I didn't know that I'm using MAMP. And by default, MAMP has MySQL 5.7. I should upgrade it.

Comment: I tried to use the second one that you wrote for the older version but the result for me returned all rows that have ct equal to 0, and it is not correct, the result should be like this ` 12 | 222 | 2 | 0 === 16 | 333 | 3 | 0 === 18 | 444 | 1 | 0 === 19 | 555 | 2 | 0 `,

Comment: @Milad . . . The correlation clause should use `fid`.  I fixed the typo.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists` as follows:

```
Select t.* from your_table t
 Where not exists
       (Select 1 from your__table tt
         Where tt.fid = t.fid and tt.tp < t.tp and tt.ct = 0)
  And t.ct = 0
```

Comment: thank you, @Popeye, the result wasn't correct, I updated the question to explain a little better

Comment: Please paste the result in comment. I want to check and refine the answer based on it

Comment: Thank you, @Popeye, I really appreciate it,  in the question I wrote what result should be like below the (more explanation) , but the ids with 12,16,18,19 should be return 

`
12 | 222 | 2  | 0 === 16 | 333 | 3  | 0 === 18 | 444 | 1  | 0 === 19 | 555 | 2  | 0

`